# Attaching a fixed, transparent, header to a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I've been trying to get this working for some time... Is there any way to put a transparent fixed header on a listview, so it looks kind of like this:

[image: Transparent sticky header]

As you scroll up, the header will eventually be a regular header with item 1 below it.

I guess I'll have to implement onScrollListener and do something like when the first visible item is item 2 in the list, start moving the listview margins by 1 pixel, until it is below the header? Or are there better ways? Any ideas on how one would do something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make a FrameLayout... and put your ListView in it first, filling the screen.  Then put a TextView on top of that.  To get the desired behavior at the top, maybe have a blank element at position 0 of the list, or just make the top padding of list item 0 have the height of your header...

Does that make sense?  The ListView should scroll underneath the TextView in a FrameLayout.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. Rather than just adding a blank element though, my suggestion would be to use `addHeaderView()` on your ListView to add a blank View that's the same size as your header.

Comment: It does make sense. Padding doesn't work though because my views have background colors, so I ended up adding a blank view the same size as my header with addheaderview as kcoppock suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RelativeLayout for that, so you can get the Z axis using some properties;)

Update:

For example using a RelativeLayout:

RelativeLayout
----ListView
----TransparentHeader

Will appear in the way you show on your image.

As a comment :Android put layout elements in the order that they are defined on your xml, so, widgets at the bottom of the layout will be at the top.

Comment: The Frame Layout will take advantage of the Z axis by default in declaration order in your XML, whereas Relative Layout does not.