# android header opacity

Tags: android, header, opacity

I am trying to build similar listView with transparent header like here [Attaching a fixed, transparent, header to a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737096/attaching-a-fixed-transparent-header-to-a-listview)
But how can i change header opacity ?
I tried in color code use alpha like: "#00bebebe" but that didnt work.

My header background "title_bar_background"

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Top color -->
<item android:bottom="20dip">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#bebebe"
             /> 
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Bottom color -->
<item android:top="20dip">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#696969" /> 
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

My header layout "custom_title"

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
.... 
android:background="@drawable/title_bar_background"
android:id="@+id/customLayout"
>
```

And my listView where i include custom_title

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
..... >


<include  
     layout="@layout/custom_title"
     android:layout_height="40dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

this work to change opacity

```
View backgroundImg = findViewById(R.id.mycustomLayout);
    Drawable background = backgroundImg.getBackground();
    background.setAlpha(40);
```

But it works only if im not including that layout in other layout. But how could i manage to set opacity when im including that layout in other one ? (Like my xml layout above)

Answer (score 2):

Find the layout by its id and change the opacity by setting Alpha.